# Is there still a Microsoft Authenticator dev API? How can I use It?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I don't know exactly if I should ask this question here, neither if I'm using the exact right tags, but... I need to add a 2FA to a system I'm developing and, while I was looking for the best available options of 2FA, we thought about adding Microsoft Authenticator support to it (We liked Authy, Google Authenticator, etc, but we tend to prefer Microsoft solutions here). It seems it used to exist a way of adding Microsoft's 2FA to our site, but is there a way to do it now in 2019? If so, is it free (We got Microsoft developer accounts... If having them is the only paid requirement, we're ok)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Microsoft and Google Authenticators just implement the [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm) mechanism to provide a serverless (read: offline, you only need an accurate timestamp) one time password mechanism. You can use any generic TOTP library to generate a user specific shared secret, possibly encode that one as QR image for ease of configuration and then validate if a provided token matches the shared secret and has been created in the last +-n seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was reading about it over the internet and found Otp.NET after I read your answer, but I still can't grasp everything... I do get that I need to use a library to get the OTP token, but how do we validate it over a cellphone?

Comment: @MilitanteDoPT you don't validate it over a cellphone, you open the app, the app generates a token from the current time and the previously configured shared secret. This token you manually type into your app where you feed the token, the current time and the shared secret to Otp.NET which then tells you if this token is valid or not

Comment: @Suchiman Is there a way to integrate with the biometric feature of the Microsoft Authenticator App instead of a OTP that the user enters?

Answer (score 27):

Microsoft Authenticator just implements the Time based OTP mechanism ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-Time_Password ).

If you do not have Azure accounts, the Microsoft authenticator can scan a QR code with the following embedded URL

otpauth://totp/UserName?secret=Some-long-secret&digits=6&issuer=CompanyName

Once the Microsoft Authenticator has scanned this QR Code, it will start showing you one time passwords.
On the server side, you can use a library like https://github.com/samdjstevens/java-totp
The library can be used to generated the secret or verify the OTPs generated by the Microsoft Authenticator.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The answer that is accepted does not even answer the question, but just states that MS and Google use TOTP

Comment: So.. if I understand you correct, there is NO NEED for an account at Microsoft and the App (Microsoft Authentificator) can be used for free)? Just (serverside) generate the secrete, generate the link and QR-code, scan the QR-code in the MS App and anything should work (without the need of am MA account)? Thanks for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get started here: https://github.com/BrandonPotter/GoogleAuthenticator
Although the library is called "Google Authenticator" it can also be used with Microsoft's Authenticator because they basically function the same way. TOTP

Answer (score 0):

This one is not free (freemium!), but since you are saying you are open to paid options...

1. Generate a "secret" code on behalf of your user:

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com/new_v2/"),
    Headers =
    {
        { "X-RapidAPI-Key", "SIGN_UP_FOR_KEY" },
        { "X-RapidAPI-Host", "microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com" },
    },
};
using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(body);
}
```

Server will return you a secret code (e.g. IH225HMVWDS3XJVY). Keep it.

2. Generate QR codes for your users:

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com/enroll/"),
    Headers =
    {
        { "X-RapidAPI-Key", "SIGN_UP_FOR_KEY" },
        { "X-RapidAPI-Host", "microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com" },
    },
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "secret", "IH225HMVWDS3XJVY" },
        { "account", "User1" },
        { "issuer", "HomeCorp" },
    }),
};
using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(body);
}
```

Server will return an url. Pull its PNG data and you get a QR code. Scan it with Microsoft Authenticator app and you'll see TOTPs being generated every 30 seconds.

3. Now validate TOTPs:

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com/validate/"),
    Headers =
    {
        { "X-RapidAPI-Key", "SIGN_UP_FOR_KEY" },
        { "X-RapidAPI-Host", "microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com" },
    },
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "secret", "IH225HMVWDS3XJVY" },
        { "code", "425079" },
    }),
};
using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(body);
}
```

There are other C# libs available to call this API (e.g. using RestSharp), RapidAPI generates code snippets in most popular programming languages/libs